# How to resize table view cell with image?

Tags: ios, swift, image, tableview

I'm trying to make a recipe search app. I am trying to get results from the API and also an image associated with these results and display them in a table view, using the basic table view cell.

When I download the image, the image frame is set to its instrinsic size, so it'll be the dimensions of the download image. When I set constraints on this image, it's smaller but you can still see the frame is effecting the text placement.

Here's what it looks like before constraints are set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHVQJ.jpg

Here's what it looks like after constraints are set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRsZy.jpg

This is my code I'm using to set the cell up:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipe", for: indexPath)
         
    cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    cell.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    cell.imageView?.image = recipeResults[indexPath.row].image
  
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(recipeResults[indexPath.row].title)"
            
    return cell
}
```

Does anyone know how I can keep the image to be 100x100 and have the text in each row lined up nicely?

I also notice I have an issue with dequeue the cell, as when I click on the row or scroll up/down, the image then turns back to it's normal big size without keeping it small. How can I fix this?

Comment: its your custom cell ?

Comment: what are the other constraint you are using on these table view cell ?

Comment: Width and height not enought, you need to give x and y position as well. And adding constraint on dequeue not a good idea, because you just keep adding constraint every time `cellForRowAt` gets called

Comment: @jawadAli It's not a custom cell. I'm using storyboard's "basic" style cell

Comment: @MoumenAlisawe I'm not using any constraints on my storyboard since I'm using a "basic" style cell. The constraints you see in the code are the only constraints I've added via code

Comment: @SmallGrammer use custom cell instead of `basic` cell. In this way you'll able to customize what component you want. Then add horizontal `UIStackView` into your cell and constraint it's `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom`. Then add an `imageView` and `label` to the `stackView`. You should give a `width` constraint to your `imageView`.

Comment: @emrcftci Thanks this solved my problem! After the comments I had the inkling I should have used a custom cell so I did and followed your instructions to make the custom cell more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width and height constraints for your `UIImage` is not enough.

Try setting it to center vertical within the cell, and add constraint with your label too. I think it's easier for you to set it in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom cell instead of `basic` cell.

In this way you'll be able to customize what component you want.

- Create your own custom cell via `.xib` or in `Interface Builder`
- Add horizontal `UIStackView` into your cell and constraint it's `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom`.
- Add an `imageView` and `label` to the `stackView`. You should give a `width` constraint to your `imageView`. In your case it is hard-coded `100`.

Comment: @SmallGrammer I've posted my comment as an answer because of others benefits. If it is works please mark as an accepted.